# Prestashop 1.7 How to Display data from database to tpl

Tags: sql, model-view-controller, smarty, prestashop-1.7

i'm new on Prestashop, i have a little problem on prestashop 1.7, i just bought a module for my orders, on the page of details when i launch smarty i can see the array $order_reference with some information, but when i go to the page of my history i can't access to this information, i don't know how to add this information to access it with my page history, do i have to create a function on history controller or class with dbclass or do u have any others solutions to add my details information of my order ?

The problem is my information is in a another table who call eo_orderreference and i can't access to it with my orders object. I think i need to write a function but as i see on internet it is wrong to write it on a tpl file, i have to do it on my class but i don't know how.
This is the information i want to add

```
SELECT 'order_reference' FROM eo_orderreference
```

Sorry i can't upload image because it contains sensible informations.

Thank for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Smarty templates are meant to display data,
you should perform your query in the PHP file that recall your TPL and then use the Prestashop

```
assign()
```

method to return data to your TPL as smarty variables that you can show at front office.

See [here](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/creation/displaying-content-in-front-office/) for more details.

Comment: Thank @user325643 i understand know how prestashop work, but now i misunderstanding what i have to do, as i understand i have to go to historycontroller.php , add a assign var  with the value of my function who get my right information, am i wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

you can create the sql query within a function either within a module or a controller.

For example:

```
public function getAccessories($id_product)
{
    // Your code
}
```

into a hook or initcontent, you can call the function on the query sql and assign it a template:

```
public function hookDiplayAccessoryExtraProduct($params)
{
    $accessories = $this->getAccessories((int)$params['id_product']);
    $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
           'accessories_custom' => $accessories,
        )
    );
        return $this->display(__FILE__, 'views/templates/front/accessory.tpl');
}
```